# CSS3 background-size:cover showing unexpected behavior

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML file as shown below.  It uses the "background-size:cover" setting on  element.

When I open the file using the File/Open option on IE9, it shows the background image covering the entire window.  This is expected behavior.

But, when I open the same file via an Apache server (http://127.0.0.1/test.html) the background image does NOT cover the entire window horizontally..... it leaves a blank vertical strip on the right end of the window.  This is NOT expected behavior.

I see the same behavior with other background image files too.  It seems that when getting the HTML page from Apache server, the "background-size:cover" setting will only enlarge the image upto some extent.  But when getting it using the File/Open option, it enlarges the background image enough to cover the entire  element width.

And, also see similar behavior with other settings of the background-size value (e.g. when I set background-size:100% 100%;).

**Here's the HTML file:**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
        body
        {
            background:url('desert.jpg');
            background-size:cover;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>

        This is a line


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it's should resolve your issue:

```
<style>
    body
    {
        background: url("desert.jpg") center center fixed no-repeat;            
        background-size: cover;
        background-color: #000;
        overflow: auto;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='desert.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='desert.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    }
</style>
```

[image]
For further explanation read this article: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_scale_background_image_to_browser_size-17590.html

Comment: I tried the suggested code.  Does not resolve the issue.  The filter settings cause the image to repeat vertically. The main issue of cover'ing the entire body element remains (when I get it from my local Apache server)

Comment: take a look at my screenshot